# Filtering google sheets column to show cells ending with one of several values

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to filter column A to see which cells end with values like .com/,.org/,.co.uk/, etc

Instead of filtering by "text ends with" dozens or hundreds of times, is there a way to combine all of these into one custom formula?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the '|' (pipe character) mean in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187880/what-does-the-pipe-character-mean-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this custom formula for:

- filter view
- conditional formatting
- data validation

---

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, ".com/$|.org/$|.co.uk/$")
```

[image: 0]